# Thinkpad T520 with sudden power cuts

Tags: linux, hardware-failure

I have a Thinkpad T520 running on Linux Mint 17. Once in a while (once a month) it has a sudden power cut, i.e.

- laptop switches off suddenly (it does not shut down properly)
- I can hear the heads of the HDD stopping (I think it is the HDD, a clattering sound)
- the laptop reboots immediately

So far I could not find any hints in `dmesg` or `syslog` (something unusual happening before the power-off).

The laptop usually is attached to the battery as well as to the power supply. Removing either of them during operation does not make the power fail.

I'm pretty sure that a too high CPU temperature is not the issue (did not hear unusual fan sound before the power cut, and stress tests did not make the laptop fail).

I usually do not shutdown the OS, I use suspend to disk or suspend to RAM, so when the power-off happens the laptop typically has a high uptime (days, weeks, months).

Any ideas how to reproduce the power fail or how to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need teer down your laptop and clean heatsink, heatpipes, CPU fan from dust, take off termal compound of CPU and GPU chips and apply new one (cooler master for example). if you can not do this, take your laptop to service and they do this job for you, good luck

Comment: So you assume that thermal issues cause the problem, however I don't see any indications for thermal issues.